# How to get Form data to Landing Page which is redirected from the form in eloqua?

Tags: javascript, eloqua

We have a form where in processing steps we have redirected the form to landing page.
I want to access the data submitted in form on the Landing page. How can i achieve this?
The Landing page with form completely acts as back end form which is retrieving data from previous form and submit.
How can i auto submit the form on Landing page with the retrieved data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to forward them to their own purl, which would be lp.com/personspurl that would be passed via the form as form data, initially using a field merge on the load to pre-populate that value as a hidden field, ideally; assuming that you already have the contact in the database. If not, then you would have to 'update contacts with form data,' then attempt to re-post the data to a secondary form which pulls in the purl value via a field merge and then redirects the user to his/her respective purl via the 'redirect to web page' -> 'send to external' & subsequent 'use value of form field' options.

Hope that makes sense.

Best,

MLH